# make GTK+ identifiers show trough youcompleteme sugesstions

Tags: vim, gtk, gtk3

I installed ycm and completions work for STL and boost, but whenever I build gtk apps I have no completion suggestions for gtk identifiers.

my ycm_extra_conf.py file has all the includes for gtk headers as well as others.

What I want is to when I type for example:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
int main()
{
GtkWi // here no suggestions that begin with GtkWi (it should suggest 'GtkWindow') 
/* rest */
}
```

as I said suggestions work for STL and boost.

Here is my vimrc config for ycm:

```
"
" YouCompleteMe options
"

"let g:ycm_register_as_syntastic_checker = 1 "default 1
let g:Show_diagnostics_ui = 1 "default 1

let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 1
let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_open_loclist_on_ycm_diags = 1 "default 1


let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 0 "default 0
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_comments_and_strings = 0 "default 0
let g:ycm_cache_omnifunc = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_use_ultisnips_completer = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1

let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '' "default ''

let g:ycm_server_use_vim_stdout = 0 "default 0 (logging to console)
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'info' "default info
let g:ycm_server_keep_logfiles = 0 "default 0

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 0 "default 0
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 0 "default 0

"let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'  "where to search for .ycm_extra_conf.py if not found
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 1

let g:ycm_goto_buffer_command = 'same-buffer' "[ 'same-buffer', 'horizontal-split', 'vertical-split', 'new-tab' ]
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { '*': 1 }

let g:ycm_key_detailed_diagnostics = '<leader>d' "default <leader>d
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-Space>'
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<S-TAB>', '<Up>']
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<TAB>', '<Down>']


nnoremap <F11> :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics <CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

These last days I'm answering my own questions more than ever.
this is because when nobody answers your question you have no other way but to find the solution on your own.

Here what I have done to make identifiers avalilable not only for gtk and C++ but that works for any language and any kind of libraries:

download exuberant-ctags
then here is the shema to create tags:

```
Find all files:
find /root_dir -type f

Find with exclusions:
find /root_dir -type d \( -path /exclude_dir1 -path exclude_dir2 \) -prune -o -print


ctags invocation:
ctags --totals --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+ialS --languages=c++ \
--sort=foldcase --langmap=C++:.h.hpp -f file_name.tags

final invocation schema
find find-options | xargs ctags ctags-options

add to vimrc
set tags+=file_name.tags;

example:
find /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -type f | xargs ctags --totals --c++-kinds=+p \
--fields=+ialS --languages=c++ --langmap=C++:.h.hpp --sort=foldcase -f gtk-3.0.tags

example:
find /opt/boost_1_55_0/boost/asio -type f | xargs ctags --totals --c++-kinds=+p \
--fields=+ialS --languages=c++ --langmap=C++:.h.hpp --sort=foldcase -f asio.tags

example: (non-recursive)
find /opt/boost_1_55_0/boost -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs ctags --totals --c++-kinds=+p \
--fields=+ialS --languages=c++ --langmap=C++:.h.hpp --sort=foldcase -f boost.tags

example: (depth 2 with exclusion)
find /opt/boost_1_55_0/boost -maxdepth 2 -type d \( -path /opt/boost_1_55_0/boost/typeof \) \
-prune -o -print | xargs ctags --totals --c++-kinds=+p \
--fields=+ialS --languages=c++ --langmap=C++:.h.hpp --sort=foldcase -f boost2.tags
```

Here is how my vimrc looks after creating the tags and putting them into tags directory:

```
212 "boost tags
213 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/boost/asio.tags;
214 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/boost/boost1.tags;
215 "set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/boost/boost2.tags;
216 
217 "tags location
218 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/gtk-3.0.tags;
219 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/glib-2.0.tags;
220 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/atk-1.0.tags;
221 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/cairo.tags;
222 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/pixman-1.tags;
223 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/pango-1.0.tags;
224 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/gio-unix-2.0.tags;
225 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/pixbuf-2.0.tags;
226 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/gtk/libpng12.tags;
227 
228 "crypto tags
229 set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/crypto/cryptopp-5.6.2.tags;
230 
231 "llvm tags
232 "set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/llvm/llvm-3.4.2.tags;
```

after this is done vim will import the tags and youcompleteme engine will use that and suggest you as you type.

these steps turned my vim into super duper powerful IDE :D

Comment: "this is because when nobody answers your question you have no other way but to find the solution on your own." No. You must look for answers *on your own* before asking random strangers. And you could simply do `set tags+=/home/user/dev/tags/**/*.tags`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I separated my tags in vimrc so I can simply comment out those which I don't need in the current project. I wish google would give you answers to random strangers but it doesn't :/

Comment: I found that the Arch Linux `ctags` in the repo "Extra" installs it from http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ which is ￼"Exuberant Ctags".

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't get semantic completion is because YCM only triggers semantic completion when you type a trigger (like .). If you want to use semantic completion based on just an identifier, then manually hit CTRL-SPACE